# Although maps are always reference types, what if they're returned from a non-pointer receiver?

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go

Supposedly maps are reference types in Go, so when returning them from functions, you don't need to pass as a pointer to the map in order for the changes to be visible outside the function body. But what if said map is returned from a method on a non-pointer struct?

For example:

```
type ExampleMapHolder struct {
    theUnexportedMap map[string]int
}

func (emp ExampleMapHolder) TheMap() map[string]int {
    return emp.theUnexportedMap
}
```

If I make a call to `TheMap()`, and then modify a value in it, will this change be visible elsewhere even though the receiver is not a pointer? I imagine it would return a reference to a map that belonged to a copy of ExampleMapHolder, but haven't been able to find an explicit answer in the docs.

Comment: Tip: Do not use the term "reference". Maps are not really reference types. Actually nothing in Go is a reference (whatever that means).

Comment: According to the Go blog they are: _"Map types are reference types, like pointers and slices"_ - [halfway down the Declaration and initialization section](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)

Comment: The term "reference type" was never precisely defined, and many have stopped using that term to avoid confusion. The description of "reference type" can be used as a reminder that those types *contain* pointers internally, and I guess it could mean anything that could be assigned to nil, but maps, slices, and pointers are all still values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why won't you just check it?

```
emp := ExampleMapHolder{make(map[string]int)}
m := emp.TheMap()
m["a"] = 1
fmt.Println(emp) // Prints {map[a:1]}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/jGZqFr97_y

Comment: I really should have. I'm getting too reliant on SO.